# udev назначение имен NIC

Tags: ubuntu

Обновил udev на ubuntu server 14.04 (установлена на VM) до версии 204-5ubuntu20.18. После перезагрузки системы ожидал получить назначение имен для NIC по [правилам](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/).

В системе имена остались eth*. В директирии `/lib/udev/rules.d/` нет файла `80-net-name-slot.rules`. В директории `/etc/udev/rules.d/` нет правил.

```
#dpkg -s udev
```

> Package: udev Status: install ok installed Priority: important Section: admin Installed-Size: 5151 Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers Architecture: amd64 Multi-Arch: foreign Source: systemd Version: 204-5ubuntu20.18 Replaces: systemd-services (<< 202-0ubuntu6) Depends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8), libblkid1 (>= 2.19.1), libc6 (>= 2.17), libcgmanager0, libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.0.2), libkmod2 (>= 5~), libnih-dbus1 (>= 1.0.0), libnih1 (>= 1.0.0), libselinux1 (>= 2.0.65), libudev1 (= 204-5ubuntu20.18), sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) | file-rc (>= 0.8.16), lsb-base (>= 3.0-6), util-linux (>= 2.16), procps

Что нужно сделать чтобы обновление заработало?

## apt-get install biosdevname

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
biosdevname is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.

## cat /proc/cmdline

BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic root=/dev/mapper/Bat--vg-root ro net.ifnames=1

## dpkg -s biosdevname

Package: biosdevname
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 107
Maintainer: Colin Watson 
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.4.1-0ubuntu6.3
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libpci3 (>= 1:3.2.1-1), udev
...

Comment: А если добавить в граб biosdevname=1 ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/628504/457538

Comment: Уже был там, но всерано не помогло. Как я понял на ubuntu server 1) используется biosdevname как default 2) использовать нужно какой-то один из возможных: biosdevname, net.ifnames или "udev rules", чтобы включить нужно передать GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT grub один из вариантов а) "" (поумолчанию biosdevname) б) "net.ifnames=1" в) "biosdevname=0"

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить пакет `biosdevname` и убрать параметр `net.ifnames=0` из всех мест в grub.